# Anti-Tactics Chess Puzzles?

Tags: tactics, puzzles, prophylaxis

Many websites (such as chess.com) provide chess tactic puzzles and I am wondering about the value of "anti-tactic" puzzles. By anti-tactic, I mean a position where if I make a careless move, then my opponent has a tactic to checkmate in a few moves or win some material forcefully. So my task is to find the best move that stops my opponent's ideas.

My questions:

1. Are these "anti-tactic" puzzles valuable?
2. Where can I find such puzzles?

Answer (score 3):

Dan Heisman wrote a book *Looking for Trouble : Recognizing and Meeting Threats in Chess*. I'd rate it as one of my better chess books & I believe it's still available as an ebook.